# Why am I not allowed to have dynamic strings for column names in PowerApps?

Tags: powerapps

The poeple who developed Powerapps thought it would be a cool idea to force functions to be static for certain properties. They even said that it is by design (msft- person on the Powerapps forums). My question is why. [image: complete foresight]

I don't work at Microsoft, and I don't even condsider my self to be an average developer, but I cannot grasp the concept of forcing fuctions, which are meant to be dynamic to resolve. Imagine if you had a table in Excel where you had a sum function that took two cells A1 and B1 , but resolved the function and set it to a string at the next run, .. what could go wrong?

What is the reason for this madness?

EDIT: Okay, seems confirmed this is **not** by design, which I'm relieved to hear.

Comment: Can you give more details about this issue? Which control is this (there are a few controls that have a `DisplayName` property)? You mentioned that the value was originally a LookUp - did it change to a constant string right after you updated the property, or only after you saved / loaded the app? As far as I know, if you have an (dynamic) expression, it shouldn't overwrite with the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know who said that this is by design - this is wrong. If you have an expression in the DisplayName property (and I was able to reproduce the same issue updating the data table control, so I'm guessing you're using the same). I work on the PowerApps team, and we'll have a fix for it coming out in a couple of weeks.

As far as we could tell, this only affects the Data Table control, please let us know if this is not the case.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed this for the Data Table control. Apparently from the documentation, RenameColumns (as well as Add, Drop) requires a hard-coded string for the column name argument. Not sure if it is somehow related, but DisplayName should definately not be affected by this.

Glad the team is working to fix these issues. Would also be great if the Data Table control had more flexibility to get the column name and not just the row when you use Selected, but I digress.